# Coffeescript --- How to create a self-initiating anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, coffeescript

How to write this in coffeescript?

```
f = (function(){
   // something
})();
```

Thanks for any tips :)

Answer (score 159):

While you can just use parentheses (e.g. `(-> foo)()`, you can avoid them by using the `do` keyword:

```
do f = -> console.log 'this runs right away'
```

The most common use of `do` is capturing variables in a loop. For instance,

```
for x in [1..3]
  do (x) ->
    setTimeout (-> console.log x), 1
```

Without the `do`, you'd just be printing the value of `x` after the loop 3 times.

Comment: You can also write `f = do -> console.log x`

Comment: @scribu Well, those two statements are very different, and yours is actually the one that I should have given. Mine assigns the function `-> console.log 'this runs right away'` to `f`, then runs it; yours runs the function and then assigns its result to `f`, as in the original question. (Though in the case of `console.log`, the return value is always `undefined` anyway.)

Comment: Exactly. Also, you can define object properties this way: `{f: do ->  // something}`

Comment: As of CoffeeScript 1.3.1 (released April 2012), `do` also lets you pass arguments to the function. To pass `1` and `2` as the parameters `x` and `y`, write `do (x = 1, y = 2) ->`. (The documentation for this feature has [gotten lost](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/2660#issuecomment-14369711), but [the issue where the feature was introduced](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/960) has some examples.)

Answer (score 19):

If you want to "alias" the arguments passed to self-invoking function in CoffeeScript, and let's say this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
(function ( global, doc ) {
  // your code in local scope goes here
})( window, document );
```

Then `do (window, document) ->` won't let you do that. The way to go is with parens then:

```
(( global, doc ) -> 
  # your code here
)( window, document )
```

Comment: `do (global=window, doc=document) -> `

Answer (score 17):

it's ridiculous easy in coffee:

```
do ->
```

will return

```
(function() {})();
```

Answer (score 6):

try to use

```
do ($ = jQuery) ->
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also combine the `do` keyword with default function parameters to seed recursive "self-initiating functions" with an initial value. Example:

```
do recursivelyPrint = (a=0) ->
  console.log a
  setTimeout (-> recursivelyPrint a + 1), 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
do ->
    #your stuff here
```

This will create a self executing closure, which is useful for scoping.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add a whole lot of new information compared  to the other answers already posted. Rather than creating a competing answer, you might add more value by posting an informative comment under another answer that adds some clarity or useful information to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I solved it:

```
f = (
    () -> "something"
)()
```

Comment: @Squeegy I wouldn't necessarily say that. The `do` keyword has some limitations that make it necessary to use the JS-style approach sometimes (see [issue 960](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/960)); `do` was really only added because of the loop-with-closures use case.

Comment: But we aren't using CoffeeScript to punch ourselves in the face like that either.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
f = () ->
  # do something
```