# Template.prototype.autorun() doesn't work inside a loop

Tags: meteor

I am using Template.prototype.autorun() inside a Template.prototype.onRendered() to reactively update a template. I want multiple autoruns so only the portion with updated data is run again. Here is how I imagine it would look:

```
...
for d in [0..6]
  @autorun ->
    console.log d
    deplanements = [ 'deplanements' ]
    for h in [0..23]
      deplanements[h + 1] = 0
      Flights.find(
        eibt:
          $gte: new Date(
            weekStart.year(), weekStart.month(), weekStart.date() + d, h
          )
          $lt: new Date(
            weekStart.year(), weekStart.month(), weekStart.date() + d, h + 1
          )
      ).forEach (flight) ->
        deplanements[h + 1] += flight.passengers
      charts[d].load columns: [
        xLabels
        deplanements
        []
      ]
```

On first render it works fine, in the console I see 0, 1... 6 and the template looks as expected. However, when I modify the collection, d prints out as 7. I don't see how that is possible. If i unroll the loop manually it works fine:

```
...
@autorun ->
  d = 0
  console.log d
  ...
@autorun ->
  d = 1
  console.log d
  ...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the `d` index referenced in each autorun is the same one, therefore after the `for` loop, `d` ends up being equal to 7. It's apparently a common pitfall. An easy fix would be to [call a self-invoking function within your `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607452/1439597) :

```
...
for d in [0..6]
  do (d) ->
    Template.instance().autorun ->
      console.log d
      deplanements = [ 'deplanements' ]
      for h in [0..23]
        deplanements[h + 1] = 0
        Flights.find(
          eibt:
            $gte: new Date(
              weekStart.year(), weekStart.month(), weekStart.date() + d, h
            )
            $lt: new Date(
              weekStart.year(), weekStart.month(), weekStart.date() + d, h + 1
            )
        ).forEach (flight) ->
          deplanements[h + 1] += flight.passengers
        charts[d].load columns: [
          xLabels
          deplanements
          []
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks! One addition: when moved inside the self executing function, 'this' references the window instead of the template instance. So @autorun needs to be Template.instance().autorun.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed :) Corrected my answer, thanks for the feedback.